# How can I query a table with key/value pairs into a JSON object using FOR JSON PATH?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an Asset table and an Attributes table, where the attributes are simple key/value pairs.

```sql
DECLARE @Asset TABLE(AssetID INT)
INSERT @Asset VALUES (1)

DECLARE @Att TABLE (AssetID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Val NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Att VALUES (1, 'height', '100px'), (1, 'width', '200px')
```

I would like to write a query that groups by Asset and contains a column with the JSON representation of all attributes. For example:

```
AssetID      Attributes
------------ -----------------------------------------------
1            {"height":"100px","width":"200px"}
```

How can I write the query so that the attribute name value becomes the key in the resulting JSON object? When I use FOR JSON PATH, the keys are the column names:

```sql
SELECT
    AssetID,
    (
        SELECT Name, Val
        FROM @Att att
        WHERE att.AssetID = asset.AssetID
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) Attributes
FROM @Asset asset
```

which returns...

```
AssetID      Attributes
------------ -----------------------------------------------
1            [{"Name":"height","Val":"100px"},{"Name":"width","Val":"200px"}]
```

Comment: Is it always Height and Width ? or it can be anything ?

Comment: It could be anything. There is no limit on the name of the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure about any native `JSON` methods to get the column data as `Key` in `JSON`. `Alias` names will be converted to key value in `JSON`.

So here is my try

You need to pivot the data to get the required key value pair format in `JSON`

If the `key` is static then

```
SELECT
    AssetID,
    (
        SELECT Max(CASE WHEN NAME = 'height' THEN Val END) AS height,
               Max(CASE WHEN NAME = 'width' THEN Val END) AS width
        FROM @Att att
        WHERE att.AssetID = asset.AssetID
        FOR JSON path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) Attributes
FROM @Asset asset
```

[`WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631354.aspx) is to remove the square brackets that surround the `JSON` output of the `FOR JSON` clause by *default*

**Result:**

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| AssetID |              Attributes              |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
|       1 | [{"height":"100px","width":"200px"}] |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

Since the key can be anything we need to use dynamic query to pivot the data

For demo I have changed the table variable to temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #Asset
  (
     AssetID INT
  )

INSERT #Asset
VALUES (1)

CREATE TABLE #Att
  (
     AssetID INT,
     NAME    NVARCHAR(100),
     Val     NVARCHAR(100)
  )

INSERT #Att
VALUES (1,'height','100px'),
       (1,'width','200px')

DECLARE @col VARCHAR(8000)= ''

SET @col = (SELECT ',Max(CASE WHEN NAME = ''' + NAME
                   + ''' THEN Val END) as ' + Quotename(NAME)
            FROM   #Att
            FOR xml path(''))
SET @col = Stuff(@col, 1, 1, '')

EXEC ('
SELECT
    AssetID,
    (
        SELECT '+@col+'
        FROM #Att att
        WHERE att.AssetID = asset.AssetID
        FOR JSON path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) Attributes
FROM #Asset asset')
```

**Result:**

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| AssetID |              Attributes              |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
|       1 | [{"height":"100px","width":"200px"}] |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks similar to an example I saw for XML. I was hoping to do this without executing dynamic SQL, but perhaps that's the only way.

Comment: @ChadGilbert - Lets wait for some gurus. May be any native `JSON` methods could be there to get it done

Comment: The converse query is easy: `SELECT [key], [value] FROM OPENJSON('{"height":"100px","width":"200px"}', '$')` so I'm hoping there's an easy and elegant way built-in

Comment: @ChadGilbert - I was checking in google for any possibility, I don't think it is possible to get the data inside column as `Key` in `JSON`.

Comment: I'll give it a few days to see if there are any other solutions, otherwise I'll mark yours as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: @ChadGilbert - Lets wait :)

Answer (score 0):

I know your original question asked for a solution using `FOR XML`, but you also said you want a solution which:

- avoids dynamic queries
- allows for an undefined set of key names

Have you considered the "stuff method" for accomplishing this, which uses the `STUFF` function along with `FOR XML`?

I've been using this for a while now successfully, though in some use cases you may run into performance concerns.

It doesn't require pivoting, doesn't require use of dynamic queries, and allows for varying numbers of key/value pairs per row.

Here is how it's done using your example above...

```
WITH 
    ASSETS AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 ASSETID, 'height' NAME, '100px' VALUE UNION
        SELECT 1 ASSETID, 'width' NAME, '200px' VALUE UNION
        SELECT 2 ASSETID, 'height' NAME, '900px' VALUE UNION
        SELECT 2 ASSETID, 'width' NAME, '1800px' VALUE UNION
        SELECT 2 ASSETID, 'randomKey' NAME, 'ABC123' VALUE
    )

SELECT 
    A.ASSETID, 
    '[' + STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                N',{"name":"' + B.NAME + '","value":"' + B.VALUE + '"}'
            FROM 
                ASSETS B
            WHERE 
                A.ASSETID = B.ASSETID               
            FOR
                XML PATH(N''), 
                TYPE
        ).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'' --the last param is blank... it replaces the leading comma with ''
    ) + ']' VALUE

FROM 
    ASSETS A
GROUP BY 
    ASSETID
```

Output:

```
ASSETID VALUE
1   [{"name":"height","value":"100px"},{"name":"width","value":"200px"}]
2   [{"name":"height","value":"900px"},{"name":"width","value":"1800px"},{"name":"randomKey","value":"ABC123"}]
```

I KNOW it's not a perfect solution to what you originally asked (because it doesn't use `FOR JSON` as your originally requested, but it is one workaround that meets all of your other criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but unescaped string concatenation is a deal breaker

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use some "fake" json composing, like this:

```
select [AssetID],
[Attributes] = (
    select '{'+STRING_AGG ('"'+[Name]+'":"'+[Val]+'"', ',')+'}'
    from @Att
    where [AssetID] = [Asset].[AssetID]) from @Asset as [Asset]
```

See an example "Create a nested JSON structure" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Answer by phrasing it as an answer rather than a question, i.e. don't start with `What about...`.  It would also benefit from a description of how your suggestion works.

Comment: Thank you for advice @toonice

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Att TABLE (AssetID INT, Attributes NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Att VALUES (1, '{"height":"100px","width":"200px"}')

SELECT AssetID, x.[Key], x.[Value]
FROM @Att
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Attributes, '$') AS x;
```

Return

```
AssetID  Key    Value
----------------------
1        height 100px
1        width  200px
```

See [Advanced JSON Techniques](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4138/advanced-json-techniques-in-sql-server-2016--part-3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Asset TABLE(AssetID INT)
INSERT @Asset VALUES (1)

DECLARE @Att TABLE (AssetID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Val NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Att VALUES (1, 'height', '100px'), (1, 'width', '200px')

DECLARE @resultJson VARCHAR(MAX) = '{}'

SELECT
    @resultJson = JSON_MODIFY(@resultJson, '$.' + Name, Val)
FROM @Att

SELECT @resultJson AS [@resultJson]
```

Return

| @resultJson |
| --- |
| {"height":"100px","width":"200px"} |